# How to read word by word but give each word to a value, and between commons to a set amout in python

Tags: python

Bad title I know, but it's hard to sum up. I have a text file that contains the following:

```
Jeffery, Ben, 5/5/2020, 2000
testinglast, testfirst, 17/5/2020, 240
```

I'm trying to write software that would format it like so:

```
Last name : Jeffery
First name: Ben
date : 5/5/2020
Points: 2000
```

I've been able to get to printing each word out by itself with no common but that's about it, as I need to run each value through a checker. Thank you for your help.

This is the closest I've gotten to it working, but it does the whole line, not each word

```
def main():
    emp_file = open('test.txt', 'r')
    name = emp_file.readline()
    while name != '':
        id_num = emp_file.readline()
        dept = emp_file.readline()

        name = name.rstrip('\n')
        id_num = id_num.rstrip('\n')
        dept = dept.rstrip('\n')

        print('name first  :', name.replace(',',''))
        print('name last  :', id_num.replace(',',''))
        print('date :', dept.replace(',',''))
        print('rewards :', dept.replace(',',''))
        print()

        name= emp_file.readline()

    emp_file.close()

main()
```

Comment: iterate this file line by line, then split on `,` and assign the values?

Comment: Can you please add some code? What have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at the CSV module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. In particular `DictReader` might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a file `tmp.txt` containing following lines:

```
Jeffery, Ben, 5/5/2020, 2000
testinglast, testfirst, 17/5/2020, 240
```

this should give you some starting help:

```
with open('tmp.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        last_name, first_name, date, points = line.split(',')
        print(f'Last name: {last_name}\n'
              f'First name: {first_name}\n'
              f'Date: {date}\n'
              f'Points: {points}\n')
```

### Output

```
Last name: Jeffery
First name:  Ben
Date:  5/5/2020
Points:  2000


Last name: testinglast
First name:  testfirst
Date:  17/5/2020
Points:  240
```

### Explanations

The little snippet does the following

- Open the file with read permission (`with open(..., 'r')`)
- Reading the file line by line (`for line in f`)
- Splitting the line at the commas (`line.split(',')` and uppacking the resulting list to variables (`last_name, first_name, date, points`)
- Formatted printing of the variables using `f-strings`

Comment: Thank you so much for explanations, I think I was mainly missing the (line.split(,)) functions, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using [dictreader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

**Code**

```
import csv

# Name of each field
fieldnames = ['Last name', 'First name', 'date', 'Points']
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  # Get csv reader as described in link above
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
  for row in reader:
    # row will be a dictionary of name/value pairs.  
    # name will be field name, value will be value for row
    for name in fieldnames:
      # show each field on a separate line
      print(f'{name} : {row[name]}')
```

**Input**

File data.csv

```
Jeffery, Ben, 5/5/2020, 2000
testinglast, testfirst, 17/5/2020, 240
```

**Output**

```
Last name : Jeffery
First name :  Ben
date :  5/5/2020
Points :  2000
Last name : testinglast
First name :  testfirst
date :  17/5/2020
Points :  240
```